# Django User model not working after being overrided

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

**Explanation** I have extended Django User model and add some fields to that.  Then I have saved the model and replaced it with the last User model using `StackedInline`. For this purpose I am using `django_rest_framework`. More specifically here is my code:

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # TODO: add Upload directory to the avatar
    avatar = models.ImageField()
    university = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    discipline = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    joined_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    '''Stacked Inline View for UserProfile'''
    model = UserProfile

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (
        UserProfileInline,
    )
```

serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

Post Request:

[image: Post Request]

**Problem** I can see the additional  fields that I have added in the User model in `django-admin`, but whenever I want to send a post request to create a new user, the additional fields are ignored! (while I have put the data in the post request, but it shows blank in admin)

[image: Django Admin]

**Question**

1. How can I fix or edit my model in order to make it works properly?
2. I have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.UserProfile'`, but I face with `"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` error, while I have added the app in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. Would someone help me to resolve it?

Comment: Have you changed the [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) setting?

Comment: Can you add `user_profile` from admin panel?

Comment: @HamidrezaAhmadi I didn't registered the user_profile in the admin page, because I just want to override the User model, not to have to separate models!

Comment: So can you add a new User?

Comment: @HamidrezaAhmadi Yeah! You can see the screenshot of my post request result at the end of my post.

Comment: So I think the problem would be from the `user serializer`. It would be helpful if you put the code of the serializer in your question as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201131/discussion-between-mostafa-ghadimi-and-hamidreza-ahmadi).

Comment: @JonClements I have tried `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.UserProfile'`. It doesn't worked and faced with an error!

Comment: @JonClements Would you please see my edited post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides [several ways to customize its user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) including:

- First: to extend the model with a `OneToOneField` related model which does not need to change the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings.
- Second: to substitute the user model with a model extending `AbstractUser`.  If you choose to do the second way you can follow [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

It seems you are going to do the first way and you have done right unless you didn't use nested serializer. In order to have an API able to create nested objects you have to use nested serialzers like described [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) in DRF docs.